# nominative or objective pronoun?

Tags: pronouns

The man, along with he and they, chopped down the tree.

or

The man, along with him and them, chopped down the tree.

I think it's the first one, but I'm not sure why.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Objective.

*Him and them* are objects of the preposition *with*, so objective case should be used.

If the sentence didn't have *with*, you would use subject (or nominative) pronouns.

> The man, he, and they chopped down the tree.